# Get Values from IEnumerable<anonymousType>

Tags: c#, iteration, anonymous-types, enumerable

I've got code to get **DisplayNameAttribute** from **PropertyInfo** and return it as a Pair

```
{Propertyname = "", DisplayName = ""}
```

```
public static IEnumerable GetDisplayNames<T>() => typeof(T).GetProperties()
                  .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false))
                  .Select(p => new
                  {
                      PropertyName = p.Name,
                      DisplayName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute),
                              false).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single().DisplayName
                  });
```

It would be fine, but I guess I don't understand anonymous types too well and I was wondering how to return value for specific item (if it is even possible - though it has to).

I thought it works like Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>, but now I know it is not.
To simplify question:

How can I iterate through such construction?

Comment: So if I use foreach loop I can get every item in format: `{ PropertyName = ProductChangeId, DisplayName = Product Change ID }`, but I need to get only to DisplayName based on PropertyName value. 

I'm starting to thing it is not possible by `IEnumerable` type. At least not without some `String.Split()` action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or could it be your are looking for a dictionary like:

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDisplayNames<T>() =>
    typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false))
        .ToDictionary(
            p => p.Name, // Key
            p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false) 
             .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>()         
             [0] // Linq not really required
             .DisplayName); // Value
```

Comment: To work with dictionary i am able to, but I was wondering if I can work with enum same way. I guess why overcomplicate things :)

Comment: @tulonbaar You could, but it's not very efficient. Linq is lazy, so every time you access it, run time reflection will be done again. While the type will not change run time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an enumeration with tuples of property and display names, then ...

... use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

```
public static IEnumerable<(string propertyName, string displayName)> GetDisplayNames<T>()
    => typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false))
        .Select(p =>
            (
                propertyName: p.Name,
                displayName: p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                 .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single().DisplayName
            )
        );
```